# JQuery autocomplete select component?

Tags: jquery, select, autocomplete

I would like a have a select component on which user can write and it uses autocomplete. The values user has typed and/or chosen from autocomplete list will be selected on the select box. Is there this kind of component in, e.g JQuery? I could use same examples and demos.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shoud have a look at the jquery autocomplete plugin [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete).It will suit your need.